# My recyclerview only update when i go to another fragment and go back

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm using firebase realtimedatabase,firestore and a recyclerview to show my data, it is a menu to a restaurant.
I'm using storefirebase to the images and realtimedatabase to others informations like name,price and description. As i'm using MVVM, i have a viewModel and a repository too. Evrything is working fine  but when i whant to the frist time show my data it pnly apper when i go to another fragment and go back.Here is my fragment code:

```
    HomeFragment

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        DataRetriever dataRetriever = new DataRetriever();
        HamburgerViewModel hamburgerViewModel;
        HamburgerViewModel.Factory factory = new HamburgerViewModel.Factory(dataRetriever);
        hamburgerViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,factory).get(HamburgerViewModel.class);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
        ProductsAdapter productsAdapter = new ProductsAdapter(getContext(),"burger");
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
        GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2,GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(productsAdapter);

        hamburgerViewModel.getProductsMutableLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),productsAdapter::update);
    }
```

I'm using the `DataRetriever` as a way to retrieve data from firebase genetically to reuse the code in others repositories.

```
class DataRetriever

 public class DataRetriever {

    private final List<Product> productList;

    public DataRetriever(){

        productList = new ArrayList<>(0);
    }

    public List<Product> get(String child, String path){
 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(path).child(child).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                try {
                    productList.clear();


                    for (DataSnapshot i: snapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Product product = i.getValue(Product.class);
                        productList.add(product);

                    }
                }catch (NullPointerException e){

                    Log.e("firebase","Error getting the data, because of null elements", e);
                    productList.clear();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                Log.e("firebase","Error getting the data", error.toException());
            }
        });
        return productList;
    }
}
```

**here is my viewModel and Repository**:

```
    public class HamburgerViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<List<Product>> liveData;

    public HamburgerViewModel(DataRetriever dataRetriever) {

        String child = "burger";
        ProductsRepository productsRepository = new ProductsRepository(child, dataRetriever);
        liveData = new MutableLiveData<List<Product>>();
        productsRepository.getAllProducts(liveData);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<Product>> getProductsMutableLiveData(){
        return liveData;
    }

public static class Factory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory{

        private final DataRetriever dataRetriever;

    public Factory(DataRetriever dataRetriever) {
        this.dataRetriever = dataRetriever;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        return (T) new HamburgerViewModel(dataRetriever);
    }
}
}
```

```
    private final List<Product> productList;

    public ProductsRepository(String child, DataRetriever dataRetriever) {
       productList = fetch(dataRetriever.get(child, "menu"));
    }

    public void getAllProducts(MutableLiveData<List<Product>> liveData){
        liveData.postValue(productList);
    }

    public void getAllProductsData(MutableLiveData<List<Product>> liveData){

        liveData.postValue(productList);
    }

    public List<Product> fetch(List<Product> productListFetched){

        productListFetched.removeIf(product -> product.getName() == null || product.getId() == null || product.getPrice() == 0 || product.getDescription() == null);

        return  productListFetched;
    }
}
```

**Adpter**

```
    private final List<Product> productList;
    private final Context context;
    private final String imagesPath;
    private final StorageReference storageReference;

    public ProductsAdapter(Context context, String imagesPath) {

        productList = new ArrayList<>(0);
        this.context = context;
        this.imagesPath = imagesPath;
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_row,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.name.setText(productList.get(position).getName());
        holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(productList.get(position).getPrice()));
        GlideApp.with(context).load(storageReference.child(imagesPath+"/"+productList.get(position).getName()+".jpg")).into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    public void update(final List<Product> productList){

        this.productList.clear();
        this.productList.addAll(productList);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView price;
        private final TextView name;
        private final ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            price = view.findViewById(R.id.price);
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageProductView);
        }
    }
}
```

While i was trying to figue out what is happenig, i noticed that there is not problem in retriever the data, but because as firebase recover data asynchronously an my `notifyDataSetChanged()` in update on observer  notify beforethe data is ready in my   `productList`. And i have no problem with this. But when my data is ready my, observer don't update my new data till i go to another fragment and go back.
So, my queistion is: how i deal with this problem or what is causing it? Is a sycronization problem? architectural problem? Bad implementation? Any help will be great, code, article, docs etc. Thanks!

Comment: There is no way you can return the `productList` as a result of a method. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks a lot it was not just a help, it increased my skills as developer.

Comment: Good to hear that, Igor ;)

Answer (score 0):

After you change the list that your adapter shows on the list view or recycler view, you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter to tell it about the change.

For more on this see the documentation of [RecyclerView.Adapter:: notifyDataSetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()).